# Using Whatsapp-web.js and MyanimeList api to send news on group

Tags: javascript, api, axios, whatsapp

As the title describe my question, I just started recently developing a WhatsApp Bot using whatsapp-web.js but the problem is that i'm bad at reading documentation, so my question is :

**Does anyone knows how to send anime and manga latest news to whatsapp using an api, like MyAnimeList Api or MYANIMENEWS api, or any other api**

**My code below which i tried :**

```
client.on('message', async message => {
const content = message.body

if (content === "anime-news") {
    const animeDb = await axios("https://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/api.xml?anime=id")
        .then(res => res.data)

    client.sendMessage(message.from, await MessageMedia.fromUrl('animeDb.url'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this kind of algorithm to solve your problem

```js
function hash(string, len=10){return result} // hash the content

let currentHash;
let chatSubsCode = ["12312@c.us","1231231@g.us","etc"];
const delay = 1000;


setInterval(()=>{
  // some code to request data
  let data = "some response"; // <- warn: it will spam API request
  let hashedData = hash(data);
  
  if(currentHash==hashedData) return;
  currentHash = hashedData;
  // send
  for(chatid of chatSubsCode) client.sendMessage(chatid, data);
},delay)
```